# Which 2nd hard drive for my MBP 2011?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive

I am looking at options for a 2nd hard drive (SSD is primary) for my 15" MBP 2011, i initially was going with a 750gb 5400rpm drive but i'm thinking about either of the following 7200rpm  drives.

1) Western Digital Scorpio Black WD7500BPKT

2) Seagate Momentus ST9750420AS

I will be running lots of Virtual Machines so i'm thinking the faster drive would be a better fit.

Are there any concerns with noise/vibration/battery drain with either of these faster drives ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the Seagate in my 2010 15" MBP and I have had 0 problems with it.  It's dead silent and there is no vibration.  My battery life stayed pretty much the same after the upgrade, but since you are looking at dual hard drives (I'm assuming you removed your optical drive) I would expect to see a slight drop in your battery life.

I would stick with the 7200rpm drives over the 5400rpm myself.

Answer (score 1):

I ever had issues with seagates drives. That started in the 90s...

My last one, a 7200rpm seagate provided in my MBP 2009... was dying after 6 months, losing clusters every day, making scary "clic" sounds. My MBP was **FROZING** around 10~30s at each dead cluster access attempt... at first, one time a week... then several times a day. *btw, if your mac freeze occasionally like that one day, check the hard drive with a tool like TechTool Pro, Disk utility won't report nothing*.

On the other hand, got 4 external Western Digital drives, no issues *at all*, even with the +5 y/o older one, and that with a pretty intensive use (like running virtual machines).
The funniest one is a big 1TB that fall from a table several times and still works perfectly.

As a side note, my MBP is now equipped with an Intel SSD + the same seagate model that Apple replaced thanks to warranty. And I don't have problems with it so far, but I'm backuping with Time machine, regularly...

Maybe I've just been unlucky with seagates, but guess my suggestion :)

Oh and of course, for VMs, 7200rpm is highly recommended (and VMs on SSD are just amazing)